# footer on bottom of viewport without overlaping with content

Tags: jquery, css, footer, css-position, overlapping

What I need is a very basic layout with only 2 main parts: content and footer.
The footer should always be on bottom of viewport.
So I have:

- Content (position:relative)
- Footer (position: fixed; bottom:0px)
  That works grate when I have few content (see [image 1](http://estudioibarra.com/test/img.jpg)).

The problem starts when the viewport is too short or have lots of content (see [image 2](http://estudioibarra.com/test/img.jpg)).

The content goes behind the footer (overlaping) and the page scroll appears.

I don't want it to go in front either. 
What I would like is this (see [image 3](http://estudioibarra.com/test/img.jpg))

The content doesn't overlap with the footer, and the page scroll only scroll the content div.

I don't know how to accomplish that or even if it can be done. 
I don't mind using jquery and I don't care for ie6.
Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Thanks for the reply's.

I'm uploading a couple of images so you can better understand what I need.

In image 1 http://estudioibarra.com/test/image1.jpg you can see the design I want, and in Image 2 http://estudioibarra.com/test/image2.jpg is the same image with some explanations.

What I want is the header always on bottom of viewport because is my menu. And I don't want the content to overlap with my menu. because the content will have more than 3 projects.

What I don't want is this http://estudioibarra.com/test/image3.jpg (content appearing behind menu).

With some of your solutions I can solve that, but only if I have a scroll in the container div. I really don't like that.

Is there to use the main page scroll to scroll the container content??

Thanks again for your time

Comment: @rsplak: See the image. All 3 images are inside it.

Comment: @thirtydot, yup, you're right

Answer (score 4):

How about simply making both content and footer `position: fixed` and place them however you want, like this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bAtVE/?

```
#content {
    position: fixed;
    height: 85%;
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
    width: 95%;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

---

```
<div id="content">
    here is content
</div>
<div id="footer">
    This is footer
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

I used `position: absolute` this time (see http://jsfiddle.net/bAtVE/1/). It is probably a better practice, as `fixed` position is not as cross-browser compatible.

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 85%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT2**:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAtVE/2/

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.
The problem I have with your solution is that the scroll only appears in the content div. I thought of that solution, but I didn't use it for that reason. 
What I want is to use the page scroll to scroll only the content in the content div.
Is that even possible?
thanks

Comment: All you need to do is to revise the CSS a bit to do (look like) exactly what you want. See the revised CSS.

Comment: I've added new images in a new question so you can see exactly what I need.
Thanks for your help

Comment: hum....if you really want the scroll bar at the side, you may simply `fix` the footer to the bottom and leave some space at the bottom of `#content`. There is still overlaps, but when the user scroll to the bottom, they can still see the full content. See the revised solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm trying to avoid the overlapping because of my translucid footer (see image 3 of my last post).
It seems that what I want can't be done, so I'll have so settle with the scroll only being in the content div.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In the example below footer will remain fixed even if you have an overflow of content in the parent element. Container dimensions can be dynamic and footer width will adjust accordingly. Footer is dependent on the container and not browser window unlike `position:fixed`. With jQuery you can do:

```
var cw = $('#container').innerWidth();

$('#header').css({
    'width': cw + "px"
});

$('#container').scroll(function() {
    $('#header').css({
        'bottom': -$('#container').scrollTop()
    })
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/M2n8Q/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The problem with this is that the content appears behind the header. And I don't want that because my header has opacity, so you can see the content behind it.

Comment: The solution is simple. wrap the content with div and position it 30px from the bottom. Check updated Solution at http://jsfiddle.net/M2n8Q/3/

Comment: I've added new images in a new question so you can see exactly what I need.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What about just fixing the footer to the bottom and giving it a `border-top` the same color as the background?

```
body { background:#eeeeed; }
#wrap { width:34em; margin:0 auto; }
#head, #foot { padding:1em 2em; }
#head, #main { background:#fff; }
#main { padding:0 2em 6em; }
#foot {
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    width:30em;
    position:fixed;
    background:#444;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1em solid #eeeeed;
}
```

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/xgafM](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/xgafM/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But I can't do that because the background of the page is a random selection of images.